# How to create android layout gradient background from middle to bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradient, background-color

How to create layout gradient background for all android device screen sizes such that the background gradient should start from the center of the screen. See screenshot below

[image]

My shape with gradient xml code is given below `my_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#f5fafd"
        android:startColor="#97d7fa" />
</shape>
```

In my layout If I add `android:background="@drawable/my_bg"` The gradient colour start from top, It should start from centre of the screen(refer my screenshot) and should support all device sizes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:centerColor` in your `my_bg.xml`

Comment: Easy solution , I have added `android:endColor="#fff"` `android:centerColor="#f5fafd"` and `android:startColor="#97d7fa"`  . But in my backgrount major potion is white . Is it possible to cover gradient about 65% of the screen

Comment: try to use same color in android:centerColor and android:startColor